# Extracting links in a class from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract links from a blog using this python code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Extract all links from a web page
=================================
Author: Laszlo Szathmary, 2011 (jabba.laci@gmail.com)
Website: https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/extract-all-links-from-a-web-page/
GitHub: https://github.com/jabbalaci/Bash-Utils

Given a webpage, extract all links.

Usage:
------
./get_links.py <URL>
"""

import sys
import urllib
import urlparse

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15'


def process(url):
    myopener = MyOpener()
    #page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    page = myopener.open(url)

    text = page.read()
    page.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        print tag['href']
# process(url)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print "Jabba's Link Extractor v0.1"
        print "Usage: %s URL [URL]..." % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)
    # else, if at least one parameter was passed
    for url in sys.argv[1:]:
        process(url)
# main()

#############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The links are from a blog where the main category is blog.xx/Music/
It will extract the links from the category blog.xx/this_album_name/ but i want to get the links from a class called quote on the sub pages under the category

How can i parse the links from the Music Category and have BS go through each title link to extract the links on the next page using the quote class?

i.e
blog.xx/Category

blog.xx/post1.html

blog.xx/post2.html

on each of the above post pages there is a quote block containing links that i would like to grab.

Im new to python and BS and have tried a few variations but at this point i need help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're wanting to *follow* links in the page to the next page, and scrape the links from that page also? The following should do this for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Extract all links from a web page
=================================
Author: Laszlo Szathmary, 2011 (jabba.laci@gmail.com)
Website: https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/extract-all-links-from-a-web-page/
GitHub: https://github.com/jabbalaci/Bash-Utils

Given a webpage, extract all links.

Usage:
------
./get_links.py <URL>
"""

import sys
import urllib
import urlparse
import re

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15'


def process(url):
    myopener = MyOpener()
    #page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    page = myopener.open(url)

    text = page.read()
    page.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

    urls = []

    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        urls.append(tag['href'])

    return urls

# process(url)


def main():


    # Store the urls we were given
    urls_queue = sys.argv[1:] 
    urls_found = []
    urls_done = []

    site_roots = []

    # Get the domains to keep us on the same domain (don't follow external links)
    for url in urls_queue:
        mre = re.match('^https?://[^/]*',url,re.IGNORECASE)
        if mre:
            # If we've found a match, add the entire matched string to site_roots
            site_roots.append( mre.group(0) )

    while len(urls_queue) > 0:

        # Get url off the top of the queue
        url = urls_queue.pop()
        urls_done.append(url)

        found = process(url)

        for uf in found:
            # I'd suggest checking to make sure it's on the same domain here
            # any() returns true if any of the elements in the list passed are True
            # In this case, if uf starts with any of the site_root strings.
            # 'not any()' is equivalent to saying 'none'
            if not any( [ uf.startswith( site_root ) for site_root in site_roots ] ):
                continue # Next url, this is off site

            if uf not in urls_found:
                urls_found.append(uf) 

            # If we don't have it in the queue, queue it up
            if uf not in urls_queue and uf not in urls_done:
                urls_queue.append(uf)

        print "Done %d; Queued %d; Found %d" % ( len(urls_done), len(urls_queue), len(urls_found) )

    print urls_found
# main()

#############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've added an url queue and a check to ensure that you don't go 'offsite' following links pointing elsewhere. It outputs all it's found at the end.

Note that this code will follow links on the secondary pages, so will probably index the entire site. You can get around this by commenting out the `urls_queue.append` bit in the main `while` loop (to stop adding more). Then just before the while loop add:

```
urls_queue = [url for inurl in sys.argv[1:] for url in process(inurl) if any([url.startswith(sr) for sr in site_roots])]
urls_queue = list( set(urls_queue) ) # Get rid of duplicates
```

This builds the initial queue, adding links in the pages provided. So for your example the links on the Category page will be added, but the links on subsequent pages will not.